# Video.js timeline scale/duration based on fragment length

Tags: javascript, html5-video, video.js

I'm trying to divide a video into fragments/chapters/markers, but in a way that the timeline length corresponds to the fragment length. So if the fragment starts at 2s and ends at 5s, the timeline scales/zooms to a duration of 3s. It basically could work like a playlist, but listing fragments within the same video.

I tried using [Media Fragments URI](https://www.w3.org/TR/media-frags/) which allow to [specify a playback range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_delivery#specifying_playback_range), e.g:

```
https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4#t=4,6
```

When comparing `video.currentTime` with the fragment start/end I could ensure set playback boundaries, but the timeline length/duration still corresponds to the entire video and not the fragment.

I also tried the solution in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61438758/949258), but setting the video.duration results in an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property duration of #<HTMLMediaElement> which has only a getter

Anyone has an idea how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance ✌️

Comment: You have two options: **(1)** Create your own controls. Use ratios to control the seeking bar width against the playback time. **(2)** Edit the Video JS source code. You can try looking at the [duration value](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/55cd188cb311bd4ef3a396a4e73fd234931a091f/src/js/player.js#L2488). You could try force-setting the duration with `player.duration = someSeconds;`. I don't use VideoJS so my own personal choice would be to create some custom UI controls. Up to you. Both things are do-able and achieve the same goal (of seeking within durations of fragments).

Comment: Thanks. Setting [`player.duration(seconds)`](https://docs.videojs.com/player.js.html#line2512) doesn't seem to work, and `video.duration` is a getter and doesn't want to be set. Prefer not to edit source code, so I guess I'm going to create custom controls.